# How to pass params from laravel to ReactJS?

Tags: laravel, reactjs

My application uses Lavarel and I have certain ReactJS components. Routing is done by Laravel. For a route `/Users/<userid>`, if the controller is `UserController.php` and view is `userview.blade.php`, how do I get the `<userid>` from the URL in my react component loaded in a div on `userview.blade.php`?

Comment: Not sure if the same applies in React as Vue JS, but just add a window.userID JS variable on the page and have the React data model use it.

Comment: so generally speaking, server side variables and client side variables are evaluated in completely different domains. are you rendering react on the server or the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try out this library from Laracasts which allows you to pass server-side data (string/array/collection) to your JavaScript via a Facade in your Controller.

This may look something like this (haven't tested it, but you get the gist).

```
public function UserController($userid)
{
    JavaScript::put([
        'userid' => $userid,
    ]);

    return View::make('yourview');
}
```

The docs further show how to access it from your view.

https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: Great answer! This still works with Laravel 8 and inside Svelte component.

Answer (score 0):

**UserController.php**
you can access the `userid` and send it to view like this:

```
public function getUser($userid) {
    return view('userview')->with('userid', $userid);
}
```

**userview.blade.php**
you can grab it (in some input) like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ $userid }}" />
```

This is, how I understand your problem. If it is not so, kindly correct me!!!