# Pass blade user.id route to react js component

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, reactjs

I need to pass the blade user.id to the react js component, however i keep getting

> app.js:56717 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/follow/undefined 419
>   (unknown status)

I followed a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603483/how-to-pass-params-from-laravel-to-reactjs), i got close, but it still doesn't help me solve the problem. Any suggestions ?

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('user/follow/{id}', 'UserController@my_follow');
```

**Profile.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class Example extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            btnText: 'Follow',
            className: 'follow-button',
            user:{
                id:this.props.data
            }
        };
    }

      myfollow(user) {
        fetch('/user/follow/'+ this.state.user.id , { method: "POST" })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
          });
      };



    btnClick(){
        this.myfollow(this.state.user.id);

        if(this.state.btnText === 'Follow'){
          this.setState({
            btnText:'Following'
          })
        } else{
          this.setState({
            btnText: 'Follow'
          })
        }


        if(this.state.className === 'follow-button'){
          this.setState({
            className: 'following-button'
          })
        }
          else{
            this.setState({
              className: 'follow-button'
            })
          }

    }




    render(){
        return (
          <div className="followdoe">
            <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)} className={this.state.className}>
              <p>{this.state.btnText}</p>
            </button>
          </div>
        );
    }

}
```

**Profile.blade.php**

```
  <div id="profile" data='{{ $user->name }}'></div>
```

This is what the back end looks like

**Post Controller.php**

```
public function my_follow(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = auth()->user();

    if($user->id != $id && $otherUser = User::find($id)){

        $user->toggleFollow($otherUser);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to change a couple things, after a bit of researching i found a solution.

**Profile.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class Example extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        let id = JSON.parse(this.props.data);
        this.state = {
            btnText: 'Follow',
            className: 'follow-button',
            user:{
                id:id
            }
        };
    }

      myfollow(user) {
        axios('/user/follow/'+ this.state.user.id , { method: "POST" })
          .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
          });
      };



    btnClick(){
        this.myfollow();

        if(this.state.btnText === 'Follow'){
          this.setState({
            btnText:'Following'
          })
        } else{
          this.setState({
            btnText: 'Follow'
          })
        }


        if(this.state.className === 'follow-button'){
          this.setState({
            className: 'following-button'
          })
        }
          else{
            this.setState({
              className: 'follow-button'
            })
          }

    }




    render(){
        return (
          <div className="followdoe">
            <button onClick={this.btnClick.bind(this)} className={this.state.className}>
              <p>{this.state.btnText}</p>
            </button>
          </div>
        );
    }

}
if (document.getElementById('profile')) {
   var data = document.getElementById('profile').getAttribute('data');
   ReactDOM.render(<Example data={data} />, document.getElementById('profile'));
}
```

**Profile.blade.php**

```
<div id="profile" data='{{ $user->id }}'></div>
```